# PHP Array Elements Cross

Tags: php

I have one `array` contains number of teams. I want each team to play with all other teams.

I have tried to do it with `for loop` but it nothing works.

the array is like this.

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 8 [3] => 9 [4] => 11 [5] => 12 )
```

I want to do it like this.

```
[0] - [1]
[0] - [2]
[0] - [3]
[0] - [4]
[0] - [5]

[1] - [2]
[1] - [3]
[1] - [4]
[1] - [5]

[2] - [3]
[2] - [4]
[2] - [5]

[3] - [4]
[3] - [5]

[4] - [5]
```

my code was like this

```
    function createMatchesStandings($teams,$homeaway,$round)
    {
        include_once('class_match.php');

        if($homeaway == 0)
        {
            // one way matches
            $numberOfMatches = count($teams) - 1;
            for($i = 0; $i<=$numberOfMatches;$i++)
            {
                $match = new Match();
                $match->standing = $this->id;
                $match->round = $round;
                $match->home_team = $teams[$i];
                $match->away_team = $teams[$i+1];
                $match->week = $i;
                $match->date = '0000-00-00';
                $match->insert();
            }


        }elseif($homeaway == 1)
        {
            // home away matches ($teams * 2) - 2

        }

    }
```

Comment: I want a pony.  Do you have a *specific question* that we can answer for you?

Comment: What's the array do? Also, I believe the keyword is 'array', not 'Array'. And don't you need commas separating the different elements of the array? (And no, I haven't looked at your actual code yet)

Comment: @ATaylor The array above is a print_r function of array `teams`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can something like to code bellow help you? (I hope I understood the question.)

```php
$teams=array(1,2,3,4,5);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($teams);$i++)
  for($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($teams);$j++)
    echo $teams[$i].' - '.$teams[$j].'<br />';
```

Comment: Thank you, but if the code create [0] - [1] at the first time then it will create another [1] - [0] right? I don't want any duplicated matches in this code..

Comment: Actually it will not. It will always start with the 'next' team, but never count backwards. I was having a similar approach in mind, but this one should work.

Comment: Though shouldn't you use 'count' instead of 'sizeof'? Just for the sake of semantics, 'sizeof' returns the size of the variable, not the size of the array, doesn't it?

Comment: I believe it doesn't matter. From PHP manual: sizeof — Alias of count()

Answer (score -1):

what is your name of the array and i can say you to  use foreach loop as

```
foreach(array["id"] as $key=>$value){
 $team[$id]=$value;// got new aaray as your team
 //now make your code for match between team[id] and array[id] 

   }
```

Comment: ...and what has that got to do with anything?